# Pixabay api won't show pictures (React jS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm using a pixabay array. I did manage to get the data from my array, but the pixabay api won't show it's pictures.
The console got the data from the array but won't show it:

[image]

This is what I hope to get:
[image]

This is my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://pixabay.com/api/?key=11095386-871fd43c33a92700d9bffb82d&q=travel&image_type=photo&pretty=true")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                console.log(result)
                this.setState({
                    apiImg: result.hits
                });
            },
            (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    error
                });
            }
        )ƒ
} // ---> This is where I fetch my api.

{
    apiImages.map(img => (
        <Card shadow={5} style={{ minWidth: '450', margin: 'auto' }}>
            <a href="/alleblogs">
                <CardTitle style={{ color: '#fff', height: '176px', background: 'url( {  } ) center / cover' }}>Golden Bridge</CardTitle>
                <CardText>
                    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis distinctio esse qui eos, ad provident,
                    </CardText>
                <CardActions border>
                    <Button style={{ color: '#8dd5e8' }}>Likes:</Button>
                    <Button style={{ color: '#8dd5e8' }}>Share</Button>
                </CardActions>
            </a></Card>
    ))
} //---> this is my card

<CardTitle style = {{ color: '#fff', height: '176px', background: 'url( {  } ) center / cover' }}> Golden Bridge</CardTitle >
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't remove code when posting code examples in your questions, also make sure to make it more readable. Welcome to stackoverflow!

The error you are getting by largeImageUrl is null is because you are iterating over apiImages and therefor you need to take the largeImageProperty from the returned object in the iterator in this case: `img`
Try below:

```
{
    apiImages.map(img => (
        <Card shadow={5} style={{ minWidth: '450', margin: 'auto' }}>
            <a href="/alleblogs">
                <CardTitle style={{ 
                    color: '#fff', 
                    height: '176px', 
                    backgroundImage: `url(${img.largeImageURL})`, 
                    backgroundPosition: 'center', 
                    backgroundSize: 'cover'
                }}>Golden Bridge</CardTitle>
                <CardText>
                    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis distinctio esse qui eos, ad provident,
                </CardText>
                <CardActions border>
                    <Button style={{ color: '#8dd5e8' }}>Likes:</Button>
                    <Button style={{ color: '#8dd5e8' }}>Share</Button>
                </CardActions>
            </a>
        </Card>
    ))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :D Also welcome! What do you mean by:
Please don't remove code when posting code examples in your questions, also make sure to make it more readable.

Comment: No problem! feel free to mark my answer as resolved if it solved your issue! What I meant by readable is that code was formatted badly and hard to read, so I took some time to fix it for you & updated first post :) And removing code, you knew  background: 'url( {  } ) center / cover' }} wasn't going to work, so I suggest you put the code that you are attempting with so it's easier to troubleshoot whats going wrong. Have a great day!

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint you but I've used your code but it still won't work :( Anyways thanks for helping! :D good day to you as well ;)

Comment: If you inspect the elements in dev tools, what does the backgroundImage: properties say?

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, should be img.largeImageURL

Comment: Wow! it worked! Thanks! Sorry I'm so slow with my responses but my computer is pretty slow as well ;)... Thanks again! http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=29e3f34&s=9#.XDDu61xKjIU

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again ;)... this will be my last question:  `apiImages.slice(0,9).map(img =>` I've used this code to give me 9 cards but what if I want the 9th array.. Is there any particular code for that one?

Comment: Glad to hear! I'm not really sure what you mean, you could add a variable like apiImages.slice(0, myCounter) that you can increment

Comment: I'm sorry, what I actually meant is that every card on my website has the same text: golden bridge and the same lorem ipsum text.. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=33pfors&s=9#.XDHa-FxKjIU How can I make sure that my first picture has, for example, another title. I don't know how to change this, because my code is a loop. I hope I've explained better ;)

Comment: well what your code is doing is looping/iterating over a series of objects in an array. If you want specific texts on each iteration you need to make sure you object contains it like it contains img.largeImageUrl. But back to your specific question on how to get the exact 9th element you would just do apiImages[9] and you would get that object in the array.

Comment: You mean like this? `apiImages[20].slice(0,9).map(img =>` because I got a type error TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Comment: No that would not work since by doing apiImages[20] you are just selecting the 20th element in apiImages and then trying to slice that object... :D

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really follow what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: a great way to learn is to add console.logs & debugger; statements to follow what happens when you try different things.

Comment: I'm sorry.. what I meant is that I want each card to be different not only the pictures... This is what I have now --> http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=9a39z9&s=9#.XDITtlxKjIU    this is what I want to achieve --> http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=289x2kz&s=9#.XDIUKVxKjIU